# How to send a GET request with headers via python

Tags: python, get, fiddler

I got fiddler to capture a GET request, I want to re send the exact request with python. 
This is the request I captured:

```
GET https://example.com/api/content/v1/products/search?page=20&page_size=25&q=&type=image HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Search-Version: v3
Accept: application/json
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36
Referer: https://example.com/search/?q=&type=image&page=20
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

Comment: You can try transmitting the HTTP request as-is using a regular TCP socket

Comment: Use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers)

Comment: You often have to export requests from Fiddler to Python you might want to use the **Export Sessions** function which can generate a curl command from a Fiddler request. Then you can convert this curl command e.g. using this [converter](https://curl.trillworks.com/) to Python code. Alternatively there is a Fiddler extension that directly generated Python code: http://www.chadsowald.com/software/fiddler-extension-request-to-code

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) module.

The `requests` module automatically supplies most of the headers for you so you most likely do not need to manually include all of them.

Since you are sending a GET request, you can use the `params` parameter to neatly form the [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

**Example:**

```py
import requests

BASE_URL = "https://example.com/api/content/v1/products/search"

headers = {
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36"
}

params = {
    "page": 20,
    "page_size": 25,
    "type": "image"
}

response = requests.get(BASE_URL, headers=headers, params=params)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests

headers = {
    'authority': 'stackoverflow.com',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'referer': 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?sort=newest&page=2&pagesize=15',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,tr-TR;q=0.8,tr;q=0.7',
    'cookie': 'prov=6bb44cc9-dfe4-1b95-a65d-5250b3b4c9fb; _ga=GA1.2.1363624981.1550767314; __qca=P0-1074700243-1550767314392; notice-ctt=4%3B1550784035760; _gid=GA1.2.1415061800.1552935051; acct=t=4CnQ70qSwPMzOe6jigQlAR28TSW%2fMxzx&s=32zlYt1%2b3TBwWVaCHxH%2bl5aDhLjmq4Xr',
}

response = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55239787/how-to-send-a-get-request-with-headers-via-python', headers=headers)
```

This is an example of how to send a get request to this page with headers.

Answer (score 0):

You may open SSL socket (https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html) to `example.com:443`, write your captured request into this socket as raw bytes, and then read HTTP response from the socket.

You may also try to use `http.client.HTTPResponse` class to read and parse HTTP response from your socket, but this class is not supposed to be instantiated directly, so some unexpected obstacles could emerge.